# Ruby hash object changed by CSV library

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-1.9

I recently encountered a strange problem:

In Ruby 1.9, with the updated CSV library, I define

```
options = {:headers => true, :col_sep => ';', :encoding => 'UTF-8'}
```

which works fine the first time I pass it as an argument to CSV.read.

But when I do the same time in the next line, with another file, the encoding is obviously ignored!

So while this works as it should:

```
options = {:headers => true, :col_sep => ';', :encoding => 'UTF-8'}
stockdata   = CSV.read('CurrentStock_1.csv', options)
auctiondata = CSV.read('Export_auktion_ebay-einstellungen.csv', {:headers => true, :col_sep => ';', :encoding => 'UTF-8'})
```

I can't shortcut like this:

```
options = {:headers => true, :col_sep => ';', :encoding => 'UTF-8'}
stockdata   = CSV.read('CurrentStock_1.csv', options)
auctiondata = CSV.read('Export_auktion_ebay-einstellungen.csv', options)
```

`auctiondata` then is all in `ASCII-8Bit`.

Now, maybe that is not a bug; can anyone tell me about this kind of behavior, is it necessary to freeze the options hash, or are there any other best practices?

Comment: A workaround may be to pass in options.dup

Comment: seems like `CSV.read` uses `Hash#delete` to extract options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug. It's an easy mistake to make, [I blogged about Rails doing this in that past too](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2009/03/leave-my-options-alone.html).

This bug was [unwittingly fixed](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-19/repository/revisions/31369) for the upcoming Ruby 1.9.3.

In the meantime, you can pass `options.dup` to avoid the side effects of `CSV.read`.

The same problem was still present with `CSV.generate` and [will be fixed for Ruby 1.9.3](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/5070) too.